# FDFImageIO error when build project with QT+VTK+ITK

Tags: c++, qt, vtk, itk

I am building a project using Qt4.8.4+vtk5.10+itk4.6. While I got into a problem that had never occured.

In the first, it shows:
link error: cannot open "4.lib".
But I never heard a "4.lib" and I think it useless. So I delete it in the Linker.

Then:
I got 30 errors saying:    error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl itk::FDFImageIOFactoryRegister__Private(void)" (?FDFImageIOFactoryRegister__Private@itk@@YAXXZ)  D:\Workplace\NeuroLab\build\moc_WidgetThreeDMesh.obj....

I search through the file system and cannot find anywhere using FDFImageXXXX. I compiled ITK twice and try to enable/disable Module_FDFImageIO, but it does not work anyway.

So, anyone have got the same error?

Comment: Just a guess but maybe the question you should be asking is "why did it try to include 4.lib and where can I find that" instead of "I deleted a dependency I didn't understand and now it's not working"

Comment: This same error is reported on ITK's nightly dashboards here: http://open.cdash.org/viewBuildError.php?buildid=3585458 This error should be reported to the ITK Community and the author of the remote FDFImageIO module.

Answer (score -1):

I find the error at last. I find that the source files I download had some errors. Because I re-download the VTK+ITK source code and recompiled them. No error report.

But there is a bug here. When you look at the lib list in vs20xx, you will find a strange 4.lib. When you integrate GDCM module into ITK, the error may probably report. The only thing you should do is add GDCM libs with full file path to your program.